# Ansible variable scope clash

Tags: variables, scope, ansible, inventory

I've got an [ansible](https://www.ansible.com/) setup that looks like this

```
inventories/
    sandbox1
    group_vars/
       all
       sandbox1
pb/
    pb1/
        run_pb1.yml
```

I've got roles and other stuff too, but I think this is enough to capture the gist of what I need to do.

I've got a variable **foo** that I am defining inside

```
inventories/group_vars/all
```

AND

```
inventories/group_vars/sandbox1
```

Now my issue is that whenever I call

```
ansible-playbook -i inventories/sandbox1 pb/pb1/run_pb1.yml
```

The playbook is run with the value of **foo**
 that is contained in **inventories/group_vars/all**... put another way, the value of foo from **inventories/group_vars/sandbox1** is not overriding the "global/all" version.

Is this the correct way to implement an inventory specific variable? I want to avoid creating mulitple playbooks for something as simple as a variable change... ie, I do not want to do something like this inside the "all" file

```
default_foo: bar
sandbox1_foo: baz
```

along with multiple playbooks, which would be the same except for the variable they reference.

Is there a way to do what I am asking?

Comment: the group_vars folder should contain the names of groups, not inventories for adding variables.  Can you share a sample of your sandbox1 inventory for further clarification?

Comment: your comment provided the solution, I was not including a group called sandbox1 in my inventory file. Thanks!

Comment: For posterity, I added my comment as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group_vars folder should contain the names of groups, not inventories for adding variables. Add a group inside your sandbox1 inventory file called "sandbox1" and it will then use those variables.